# Vector going out of scope

Tags: c++, vector, struct, scope

So I am having an issue with my vector of structs going out of scope. I'm not sure why. I have used vectors before but for some reason this is not working. I have looked at several forums and tried several different thing to fix the issue.

both the constructor and the DirectMap method are being called in the main. I want the vector to stay in scope for both methods. Is this possible? Thanks Alot for helping guys!

Heres how I declare it in the headerfile:

```
struct input
{
    bool dirtyBit;
    int statusBit; //0 not in cache, 1 in cache, 2 in 2nd cache
    bool writeStatus; //write = 1 read = 0
    int address;
    int indivBlockIndex;
    int indivBlockOffset;
};
    class Cache
    {

    public:

        vector<input *> dataBase;
        Cache(string);
        ~Cache();

        void DirectMapped(int, int);
    };
```

Heres how I use it:

```
Cache::Cache(string infile)
{
    ifstream in(infile);

    string readWriteStatus;
    int Addr;
    while (in >> readWriteStatus >> hex >> Addr)
    {
        input *contents;
            contents = new input;
        contents->dirtyBit = false;
        contents->statusBit = 0;
        dataBase.push_back(contents);   
    }
}

Cache::~Cache(){}

void Cache::DirectMapped(int cacheSize, int blockSize)
{
    //initial stats needed
    int blockCount = cacheSize/blockSize; //number of total blocks
    //clear out the cache
    for (int i = 0; i <= dataBase.size(); i++)
        dataBase[i]->statusBit = 0;
//other irrelevent stuff after this
}
```

Again, thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: never allocate memory for `contents` and push_back to dataBase?

Comment: You're in *undefined behaviour* land: you need to allocate memory for `countents` (and deallocate it).

Comment: Your question (nor code) makes any sense... Firstly you have a vector of pointers, and yet you don't instantiate the structure, you declare a pointer and then attempt to set some members and then push this pointer into the vector... you really need to review your code...

Comment: Why do you think the vector is going out of scope? If you get actual error messages tell us what they say

Comment: Why are you calling member function inside the constructor???? how can member variable dataBase go out of scope inside the class itself??? Just allocate memory for the struct

Comment: Did you edit the question in the first five minutes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're storing pointers to `input` structs in your vector, but you never made them point anywhere. A simple fix might be to change

```
input *contents;
```

to

```
input *contents = new input;
```

However, managing a vector of raw points has all kinds of annoying consequences. In your particular case, I see no reason to hold a vector of pointers in the first place. Just use

```
vector<input> dataBase;
```

...and store the actual structures.

Comment: I removed some code so that i tihnk it makes more sense. If i use the final line you write (which is how i intiially implemented it) it automatically went out of scope when it went out of the constructor.

Comment: @user3084848: The `dataBase` certainly doesn't go out of scope when existing the constructor, it's a member of the class i.e. accessible by all functions. It only goes out of scope when exiting the destructor of the class. You can verify this by adding a custom `struct` member to your class which prints a message in its destructor, and then observe when that message gets printed.